# PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumberToE164 indesired method result

Tags: android, android-studio, android-contacts

I am trying to format a phone number to E164 , in vain :

```
//Detects outgoing call :   
private class MyOutCallsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    public MyOutCallsReceiver() {super();}
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String outgoingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
        Log.v("OUTCALL-outgoing",outgoingNumber);
        String phone = MyApplication.TryFormatPhoneNumberToE164(outgoingNumber);
        Log.v("OUTCALL-phone",phone);
    }
```

Logcat:

> 11-11 14:23:19.836 495-495/ma.altaiir.app V/OUTCALL-outgoing:
> 0612345678

> 11-11 14:23:19.841 495-495/ma.altaiir.app V/OUTCALL-phone:
> 0612345678

Formatting method :

```
public static String TryFormatPhoneNumberToE164(String phone){
    String result = PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumberToE164(phone,_CountryIsoCode);
    if(result == null){result = PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumberToE164(PhoneNumberUtils.normalizeNumber(phone),_CountryIsoCode);}
    Log.v("COUNTRYISOCODE/NUMB",_CountryIsoCode + "/" + phone + "/" + result);
    if(result == null){return phone;}else{ return result;}
}
```

Logcat:

> 11-11 14:23:19.841 495-495/ma.altaiir.app V/COUNTRYISOCODE/NUMB:
> ma/0612345678/null

All this means , the method is just returning null whatever I do to avoid this, is this known drawback or it is something I do wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i ended up using libphonenumber wich resolved all my number parsing problems, but still wondering why builin method do not work ! 
Anyways, for any one facing the sale parsing problems, try https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber